# Spring MVC - All requests to application in Tomcat result in Error 404 after war packaging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

**EDIT: Fixed the issue by making the main Startup class extend SpringBootServletInitializer.**

I'm trying to deploy a Spring MVC project with Maven using webapp-runner and .war packaging.

It works great on the local Tomcat installation when running through IntelliJ's run configuration but when i try to run the war package it always returns not found.

I run it with the following command:

```
java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war
```

Here is my project structure:

[image]

> An important note to make here is that if I add a random **index.html**
>   file inside the **webapp** directory it is mapped correctly and found
>   with a 200 OK.

I'm pretty new to the Spring technology so if you could help me out with this app's architecture so the request mappings work after packaging I'll be very thankful.

Here is my HomeController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

What should I change? Should my Thymeleaf templates be inside the webapp folder? Why wont Tomcat locate them with the current way of mapping after packaging?

Comment: You are using Spring BOot why not simply run the war instead of what you do now on the commandline? Also when using a war have you followed the Spring Boot guide on creating a deployable war?

Comment: @M.Deinum "Webapp runner is designed to allow you to launch an exploded or compressed war that is on your filesystem into a tomcat container with a simple java -jar command."
And yes, the war is deployable

Comment: I don't doubt it is deployable but have you taken the steps as mentioned in the guide to make it a war.

Answer (score 0):

In a war file, the URL context is the name of the war file.  So in your case its `http://host:port/slupov-personal/`.

Comment: the result is still the same. This URL hits 404 again.

Comment: what URL you hitting?

Comment: both http://localhost:8080/ and http://localhost:8080/slupov-personal/ return 404